# Backup in a external USB drive

Tags: backup, external-hdd

What's the best way to maintaing a incremental backup on a external USB Drive (HD 500 GB)?
There are any GUI tool for this? or a easy shell script to make a backup of my home folder (music, video, documents...)

Answer (score 3):

I think best opensource tool backup will be "rsync". It has the feature to do incremental backups.You can use grsync as it's front end.

Answer (score 1):

Personally for backup all my home file I use Back In Time, it's a great applications! You can find more info at http://backintime.le-web.org/